# How to generate jacoco code coverage reports from jacoco.exec generated on remote server

Tags: jenkins, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm trying to generate jacoco code coverage reports from the jacoco exec file (generated on remote server) which I have copied into Jenkins workspace.

My requirement is to start the server in a remote location, then executes scenario tests against the remote server and get the code coverage.

For that purpose, I have placed the jacoco agent in the server side, then attach the jacoco agent as a JVM option and do the instrumentation on the server side. This will automatically generate an empty jacoco exec file in the server side when the server starts up. Then I execute the tests and shutdown the server. Next the generated jacoco exec has copied to jenkins workspace and create a freestyle project. Then added only the exec file in the "Record jacoco coverage report" under "Post-build actions". After that when I triggered a build, I got the results as "Overall coverage: class: 0, method: 0, line: 0, branch: 0, instruction: 0". Could you please help me to get this solved and generate the reports.

I'm using Jenkins 2.138.2 version and jacoco plugin 3.0.4 version.

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding the `jacoco.exec` file contains only the information which code has been executed. So in order to measure the code coverage, this information has to be compared with the `class` files.

So try to add the `class` files to the workspace.

If you also want to drill down into the source code in jenkins, add the source code to your workspace.

Comment: I've tried it that way by adding class files to workspace. But still I cannot generate reports. But I can generate the report by adding those class file paths to the POM. Is there any way to generate reports in server side itself in server shutdown.

Comment: can you please add the log from jenkins? Also maybe a screenshot from jenkins configuration / workspace

Comment: Please find the attachments as below.

Comment: As from your [Jenkins Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPu1Y.png) you do not include any class files. try to use the default plugin configuration or configure the patterns in a way to reflect your workspace.

Comment: I have a set of .jar files which I need to pass into class files section. But I cannot provide the jar files with the default plugin configuration. How can I pass them?

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you want to analyse the classes which are in the jar file? I dont think you can add jar files to the plugin configuration. try to `unzip` the `jar`.

Comment: Still I cannot get the reports, even after adding the class files extracted from jars. Please find the jenkins console attached herewith.   Console: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zEl_ZijkZp49H4-5fUGGXPDpRVaKPG4P/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your [logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zEl_ZijkZp49H4-5fUGGXPDpRVaKPG4P/view?usp=sharing) say otherwise: `Overall coverage: class: 57, method: 35, line: 13, branch: 6, instruction: 11` When you click on the build number, there should be a `Coverage Report` link.

Comment: Yes. I can view the code coverage reports there. But can't we download those reports. From the download link, I can download only the exec file. There's no report folder in my workspace as well.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [jacoco-maven-plugin](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html) or ask a new Question because in my opinion this Question is answered.